# Any shortcut or command to show opened files in current editor group - VSCode

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I can see opened files in 1st group (created via split editor) using command "`show editors in first group`", in 2nd group "`show editors in second group`" and I can also see all opened files including all groups "`show all editors`".

Bu, how to see the files opened only in the *currently focused group*?

Answer (score 2):

VS Code has added this now. Go to File-->Preferences-->Keyboard Shortcuts.
2. Scroll down PAST the keys that have assignments to the unassigned keys. It's under "Show Editors in Active Group"
3. Since it has no assignment, click on the '+' symbol to give it an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The existed answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53537818/7860292 is right.

And it is also okay to directly type `edt active` in the FilePicker ~

---

And shortcut configs like following would be easy to toggle `in active group` or `in all groups`:

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+oem_period",
        "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+oem_period",
        "command": "workbench.action.showEditorsInActiveGroup",
        "when": "inFilesPicker && inQuickOpen",
    },
```

---

However, I do not find anything like `show editors in first group` as said in question, are those deprecated ? ...